# What value must I fill when retrive intent.extra.getLong("KEY", what value mus I fill here)

Tags: android

I have question.
when you do

`FirstActivity.class`

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("KEY", "Some integer ID maybe null");
startactivity(intent);
```

`NewActivtity.class`

```
Intent intent = getIntent()
Integer someId = intent.getExtraInt("KEY", What value must i put?) <<<--- here the problem what must I put?
```

for now I put "-1", but someone tell me to not used -1. maybe someone can give me the best pratice about default value.

Comment: there's no best practice for a default value, it's exactly that, a default value, it's up to you to know and handle what happens when something isn't found

Comment: The second parameter is just the default value ... suppose if you do not pass the value from the previous activity then the default value will be returned automatically

Comment: I read the doc and I see there default value for int, float, and etch must not null.
maybe I can retrieve with another way?

Answer (score 1):

I think best default value is that which you can clearly disguised from actual values which you can put in putExtra so you can clearly guess whether value is original or it just a default value.

Answer (score 1):

Any value should work for the default value. It's just a backup incase there's nothing found when retrieving data.

Answer (score 0):

Activity.RESULT_OK = -1, so, maybe this 'someone' who told you not to use -1 meant that in some cases, for exaple when you use startActivityForResult(), you can get same values.